# Weird cURL behaviour on POST request

Tags: json, bash, post, curl

I have a small issue with cURL and my RESTful API.

From Postman I perform a POST request with raw body with the following JSON:

```
{
    "name" : "bob",
    "age" : 22
}
```

The JSON is received on the Web service, which performs whatever it has to do, returning a successful message sent as a response by my API (just to check that everything is working).

I am trying to fabricate a bash script which does, among other things, the same exact POST request. I do it in this way: `curl -X POST -d '{"name":"bob","age":22}' http://my.url/my/API` (I know `-X POST` is not necessary as I've read `-d` makes cURL automatically perform a POST request). Weirdly enough, the latter returns the following error: `{"code":"InternalError","message":"Unexpected token o"}`.

I do not understand what is wrong with this. Am I missing some flag? I also tried to specify the header of the cURL request (`-H "Content-Type: application/json"`) but I get the same result.

EDIT: Putting quotes around the number in the JSON (`"age":"22"`) gives the same result.

EDIT2: I realised that server-side `req.body` is a string when I perform the request from Postman, while it is an Object when performing the request from cURL. I can easily fix this server side, but I'd like to know if somebody knows why this happens.

Comment: add `--trace-ascii logdump.txt` to the command line and investigate exactly what curl sends/receives

Comment: Thanks. Everything seems fine. I correctly send the JSON and receive `400 Bad Request` because of that error. I think I found something server side though. I updated the question.